# Error: Activity result fragment index out of range: 0x2fffe

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, onactivityresult

When im trying to delete a show with an AsyncTask. I want to call finish() after the AsyncTask has been completed and return an Intent with the result.

from the activity:

```
new DeleteShowTask().execute();
Intent intent = new Intent(SeasonActivity.this, FragmentShows.class); // I'm not sure if this works
intent.putExtra("tvdbid", tvdbId);
setResult(DELETECODE, intent);
finish();
```

then in the fragment i have this:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("RESULTCODE", resultCode + "");
        Log.d("REQUEST CODE", requestCode +"");
        if (resultCode == SeasonActivity.DELETECODE)
        {
            if (requestCode == SeasonActivity.SHOW)
            {
                String tvdbid = data.getStringExtra("tvdbid");
                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    SickbeardSerie serie = adapter.getItem(i);
                    if (serie.getTvdbId().equals(tvdbid))
                    {
                        adapter.remove(serie);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But it seems like it doenst run through this `onAcitivityResult()`.
I have logged the `onActivityResult()` as you see but i dont get any logs.
Only thing i get is: `10-19 16:21:44.631: W/FragmentActivity(27672): Activity result fragment index out of range: 0x2fffe`

Comment: @luksprog i have tried that but without result. Someone said that already here in this question but probally removed it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it for now by using a work around. 
I now reload my AsyncTask in the onResume() instead of just removing an item from the arraylist and calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). But its not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you using a Fragment in a another Fragment. You should be call

```
getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_PICTURE);
```